# Laravel 5.2 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, pivot-table

I'm having issues with the migration registering in the `migrations` table and I'm getting the following error when I run `php artisan migrate`:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key 
constraint (SQL: alter table `surgeon_surgeon_specialty` add 
constraint `surgeon_surgeon_specialty_surgeon_id_foreign` foreign key 
(`surgeon_id`) references `surgeon` (`id`) on delete cascade)

[PDOException]                                                          
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Here's my files currently:

`Surgeons Table Migration`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSurgeonsTable extends Migration
{
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('surgeons', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->string('surgeon_name', 30)->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
 }

 /**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function down()
 {
    Schema::drop('surgeons');
 }
}
```

`Surgeon Specialties Table Migration`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSurgeonSpecialtiesTable extends Migration
{
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('surgeon_specialties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('surgeon_specialty_name');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unique(['surgeon_specialty_name','user_id']);
    });
 }

 /**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function down()
 {
    Schema::drop('surgeon_specialties');
 }
}
```

Then I used the `Laravel-5-Generators-Extended` package to generate the

`Surgeon Surgeon Specialty Table Migration`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSurgeonSurgeonSpecialtyPivotTable extends Migration
{
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('surgeon_surgeon_specialty', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('surgeon_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('surgeon_id')->references('id')->on('surgeon')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('surgeon_specialty_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('surgeon_specialty_id')->references('id')->on('surgeon_specialties')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['surgeon_id', 'surgeon_specialty_id']);
    });
 }

 /**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function down()
 {
    // Schema::drop('surgeon_specialty_surgeon');
    Schema::drop('surgeon_surgeon_specialty');
 }
}
```

But changed it to this per a friends suggestion:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSurgeonSpecialtiesTable extends Migration
{
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('surgeon_specialties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('surgeon_specialty_name');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unique(['surgeon_specialty_name','user_id']);
    });
 }

 /**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function down()
 {
    Schema::drop('surgeon_specialties');
 }
}
```

**`The table does migrate...`**

...however, I am still getting the error. Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Just to double check, do the tables already exist in your database and you're just wanting to remove the foreign key constraints?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Laravel 8. I'm not sure if it's relevant to this post or not. This happens when you create the migration for the `many` before the `one` part of `one-to-many` relationship. In your case I guess you created migration for `items` before `users`. Simply rename your migration files according to your relationships. Your `surgeon` migration date should be earlier to be created before `surgeon_surgeon_specialty` table.

Also I suggest to declare table name of `Surgeon` model:

```
class Surgeon extends Model {
    public $table = 'surgeons';
}
```

This is because I see Laravel couldn't determine your table name based on your model class.